# What does "${line#?}" mean in a script?

Tags: shell-script, shell

I'm trying to understand one script, which uses this command: `set -- ${line#?}`. I understand the set command and the curly brackets. But I can't find any explanation for the "#?" part.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`${line#?}`, a standard `sh` parameter expansion operator (originated in the Korn shell) simply removes the first character from the variable `line`.  For example:

```
$ line=abc; echo "${line#?}"
bc
```

More generally, `${variablename#word}` removes `word` from the *beginning* of the contents of `variablename`.  This is called *prefix removal*.  `word` is treated as a glob which means that `?` matches any single character.

#### Documentation

From `man bash` (where `bash` is the GNU implementation of an `sh` interpreter):

> `${parameter#word}`
>     `${parameter##word}`
> **Remove matching prefix pattern.**  The `word` is expanded to  produce  a  pattern
> just  as in pathname expansion, and matched against the expanded value of parameter using the rules described under Pattern Matching below.  If the  pat‐
> tern  matches the beginning of the value of parameter, then the result of the
> expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest matching  pattern  (the  `#`  case)  or  the  longest matching pattern (the `##` case)
> deleted.  If parameter is `@` or `*`, the pattern removal operation is applied to
> each  positional  parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.
> If parameter is an array variable subscripted with `@` or `*`,  the  pattern  removal  operation  is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the ex‐
> pansion is the resultant list.

#### Aside: Suffix removal

Just as `${parameter#word}` and `${parameter##word}` do *prefix* removal, it is helpful to know that the shell also offers `${parameter%word}` and `${parameter%%word}` which do *suffix* removal.  Suffix removal is commonly used to remove extensions from file names:

```
$ name=file.jpg; echo "${name%.jpg}"
file
```

Comment: That's what I kinda assumed, thanks for your answer!

Comment: It might be helpful to mention that `%`/`%%` is also available (I use it far more often, to strip extensions).

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Good suggestion.  I just added a section to mention suffix removal.